# Uploading byte array to MYSQL shows empty field (nothing uploaded?)

Tags: serialization, file-upload, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to write a script which opens a file with UniFileViewer, sets a path to the file and passes it to various methods which serialize it and upload it to my MYSQL server. When I run the script it executes without problems but the result is 0 bytes uploaded to the database. I must have missed something here...

```
 public class FileOpen : MonoBehaviour
{

public UITexture ProfilePic;
public static Texture2D tex = null;
public static String selectedFilePath;

void openFile()
{
    UniFileBrowser.use.OpenFileWindow(OpenFile);

}

public static Texture2D LoadPNG(string selectedFilePath)
{

    byte[] fileData;


        fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(selectedFilePath);
        tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        tex.LoadImage(fileData); //..this will auto-resize the texture dimensions.

    return tex;
           }
```

//OPENS THE FILE AND SENDS IT TO THE SERVER
    void OpenFile(string filePath)
    {
        selectedFilePath = filePath;
        LoadPNG(selectedFilePath);

```
    Texture2D uploadFile = tex;
    byte[] bytes = uploadFile.EncodeToPNG();
    string fileToSend = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        string[] datas = new string[1];
        datas[0] = fileToSend;
        LoginPro.Manager.ExecuteOnServer("SaveFile", SendToServer_Success, SendToServer_Error, datas);




}
```